# I'm looking for the sequence $\Big\{ \frac{n}{n+1}\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}} \Big\}$ converges or diverges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm looking for the sequence $$\Big\{ \frac{n}{n+1}\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}} \Big\}$$ converges or diverges.

I tried $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n}{n+1}\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}}_{1}\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$$

As for each $n$ we have to $-1, 1$ or $0$ in response, then it means that the limit does not exist and therefore the sequence is divergent?

Note. If it becomes complicated to understand something, I apologize, that is not write English, and this hinders a lot. I'm sorry.

Comment: Correct try!${}$

Comment: non-zero convergent $\times$ divergent = divergent

Comment: The limit points of the sequence are -1,0 and 1, so it is not convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already you have noted that $$\left(\sin\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)=
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
1, & \text{if $n=4k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
-1,& \text{if $n=4k+3$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{cases}$$ is divergent.
Suppose $$\left(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\sin\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$ is convergent. Then it can show that $\left(\sin\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right)$ is also convergent.
A contradiction!